# 2 websites setup, switching betwen forces uses to re-login

Tags: asp.net, webforms, forms-authentication

All,

I have two asp.net 2.x websites (web forms based application) setup as virtual directories under same root website.
As a matter of fact it is the same website code under two different virtual directories.
I am using asp.net forms authentication for both.

When a user logs into the first website and then (immediately) opens another IE window and logs-in to the second website, upon returning to the first website (first IE window) he is logged out and has to log-in again. When he logs-in back to the first website and returns to the second website, now he is logged out there.

In summary, I would like to have a single user to be logged-in to two websites simultaneously and be able to switch between them constantly w/out being logged out.

What is causing this issue and is there work-around?

Comment: Does it work in other browsers - Chrome, FireFox, Safari? Does it work between two different browsers - site 1 in Chrome and site 2 in IE?

Comment: Identical behavior in Firefox, and Chrome. What is interesting though, I don't have this problem when I mix the browsers. For ex, open first site in Firefox, and second site in IE. I can then switch around between the sites without being logged out.

Comment: This is cause by the use of the same authentication cookie. You need to disctin that some way...

Comment: That was it guys (same cookie name), thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by users above, I was using same cookie name for both apps.
Resolved.